# Prevent MySQL changing DATETIME

Tags: mysql, datetime

I'm having some problems reliably saving a DATETIME in MySQL. Oh the simple things!

I can confirm that the date string sent to MySQL is:-

`'2015-07-18T09:00:00'`

Yet, when I look at the saved data within MySQL, it reports the date as:-

`2015-07-18 10:00:00`

I checked my `@@global.time_zone`, it was originally set to `SYSTEM`, but I've changed that to `'+00:00'` - this has made no difference.

Basically, I want MySQL to stop changing the dates. I want the time I send, to be the time that is saved. I don't care about timezones, DST or what way the wind is blowing.

-- Would anyone advise saving dates as VARCHAR strings?

Help appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem while using mysql with node. Fixed by setting timezone to UTC+0 in connection settings:

```
{
    connectionLimit: 10,
    host:'myhost',
    user: 'myuser',
    password: 'mypassword',
    database: 'mydatabase',
    timezone: 'UTC+0'
}
```